# Compaq 6510b in boot loop after BIOS update

Tags: boot, bios, compaq-laptop

I have here an HP Compaq 6510b, which said at boot "your bios failed to complete the update. " and then something like "you may have to redo it". and then it was starting normally.
The bios version was F.16.
I then tried to download the latest bios from the HP website, F.21 with a windows installer and ran it.
It completed the update of the bios without errors, and then rebooted. After reboot, i still get the same statement that the bios failed to complete the update, but this time it does not boot anymore, rather, after this it goes into a loop.

I also tried to search on ebay for a bios chip, but they say it has to be soldered, and i cannot even find where..
Then i tried to contact HP, but  they say that the machine is out of warranty, and i have to pay to get support (and most likely they wont be able to do anything)

I honestly do not know what to do. All the HP laptops i had on my hand had some kind of troubles of this kind, where the hardware was still good, but some defect fried the machine.
Can somebody help me here?
thanks!

Comment: I'd try to re-flash using the FreeDOS image since you can't boot to Windows.  The fact that it started displaying that message before you even attempted to flash the BIOS suggests you might have an actual hardware failure where the BIOS can't be read.

Comment: The problem is that now it does not even get to booting anything.. I have a burned image with the freedos release with the bios updater, but it loops before it gets there :(